# PHP - How to write a User class that usable in other projects?

Tags: php, dry

I'm developing Telegram Bot in PHP. At All of my projects i need check user register status and if not registered, store user info. for each project i wrote this step again and again.

Is there any ways to write a user class that usable ( whit some bit change ) in other projects and avoid this repeat?

This is my code.

```
// File: index.php

$user = User::isRegistered($this->telegram->UserID());
if ($user === false) {
    $this->user = User::register($this->telegram);
} else
    $this->user = $user;
```

And this my User class

```
// File: User.php 

class User
{
    public static function isRegistered($telegram_id)
    {
        $user = SlmUsers::find()->where(['telegram_id' => $telegram_id])->one();
        if ($user)
            return $user;
        return FALSE;
    }

    public static function register(\Telegram $telegram)
    {
        $nickname = $telegram->FirstName() . ' ' . $telegram->LastName();
        $nickname = mb_substr($nickname,0,128);

        $user = new SlmUsers();
        $user->telegram_id = $telegram->UserID();
        $user->nickname = $nickname;
        $user->telegram_username = $telegram->Username();
        $user->message_id = 0;
        $user->updated_at = date('U');
        $user->last_request  = 'new';
        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

but users table filed are different in each project so for store new user in other projects i should change all field of `User::register`. how i can avoid this? i want write a class do this works whit the lowest change in the origin class (User.php).

Comment: Show us, what you are writing repeatedly?

Comment: Updated, sample codes added.

Answer (score 0):

create one class file and define the function which you are going to use repeatedly in this classs file.
Import this file in the file where you want to use this function and call that function using the object of this class file

Comment: what about this ? `users table filed are different in each project so for store new user in other projects i should change all field of User::register`

Comment: Yes you can do this.. bt make sure to import the files wherever you going to use that function

Comment: I'm looking for way does not edit the origin class. is there any way to write a class that does not need to edit `register` method's database fields in new projects?

Comment: you can send parameters based on your requirement to the function, and check the conditions based on your requirement inside that function.    hope this will work